# MySQL error 1064 while using PHP variables in query

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","12369","medical");
    $data1 = $_SESSION["symp1"];
    $data2 = $_SESSION["symp2"];
    $data3 = $_SESSION["symp3"];
    $data4 = $_SESSION["symp4"];
    $finalData = implode(' ', array($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4));
    $userinput = $_REQUEST["answer"];
    $dname=$_SESSION["dname"];
    $dname = str_replace(' ', '_', $dname);
    echo $dname."  <br>";
    $sql = " UPDATE diseases SET UserInput = $finalData WHERE Name =   $dname ";
    if($userinput=='yes'){  
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo "Values inserted";
            $_SESSION["info"] = "yes";
            header('Location: http://localhost/medical/last.php');
    }else{
            echo mysqli_errno($con);
            $_SESSION["info"] = "no";
            //header('Location: http://localhost/medical/last.php');
    }
   }
?>
```

I'm getting error 1064? I already read answers to similar question, but my code doesn't work. My table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `diseases` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Symptoms` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Medicines` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UserInput` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

What's wrong in my code? Thanks

Comment: Read the error text to know what  the errorno means

Comment: Add `'` around your PHP variables in the query string.

Comment: $sql = " UPDATE diseases SET UserInput = '$finalData' WHERE ``Name`` =   '$dname' ";

Comment: `Name` is actually a reserved word and should not be used really. If you do use it, then you must always wrap that column name in backticks

Comment: i know my backticks not working in comments

Comment: Why don't you use parameters while you use mysqli?

Comment: Thanks Prerak, it worked!

Comment: Also string columns must have their data wrapped in a single quote like this `$sql = "UPDATE \`diseases\` SET \`UserInput\` = '$finalData' WHERE \`Name\` = '$dname' ";`

Comment: @NeerajNegi you could accept my answer to close the question as answered. My question is the same as Prerak Sola points out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$sql = " UPDATE diseases SET UserInput = $finalData WHERE Name =   $dname ";
```

to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `diseases` SET `UserInput` = '$finalData' WHERE `Name` = '$dname'";
```

Add single quotes around variables that contain a string.
Add backticks around columns and table to prevent mysql reserved words error

It would be even better to use [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) do the following:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE `diseases` SET `UserInput` = ? WHERE `Name` = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $finalData, $dname);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message should state, you have an error in your SQL syntax:

> MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Surround your data by single quotes and you are good to go. Furthermore, `Name` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). You can still use it in your query, though, but you should consider escaping table names with backticks:

```
$sql = " UPDATE diseases SET `UserInput` = '$finalData' WHERE `Name` = '$dname' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single qoutes around your data:

```
 $sql = " UPDATE diseases SET UserInput = '$finalData' WHERE Name =   '$dname' ";
```

or better use prepared statements